# Duplicate questions: what to do?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a [question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/808/is-this-study-stating-red-algae-reduces-cold-virus-by-92-believable), and I got an answer. However I then realized there were more medic studies about this issue, so I figured I should complete my question. However if I changed it, I had to remove the right answer mark I had given. So I asked a [new question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/831/are-these-studies-about-red-algae-reducing-cold-virus-by-92-believable). This was marked as duplicated.

I wondering if I should edit any of them, or do something else.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with your new question is that the *answerable* part is indeed a duplicate. In addition, you have added a reference to five studies and asked:

> I found some "similar" studies [2,3, 4, 5 ,6] but I lack the competence to assert their value. Does someone have some perspective on this? Are these believable studies? Was it well designed, and has it been duplicated?

Ignoring the perspective question, there are three questions asked about each of 5 studies, i.e. 15 questions. (Possibly, “believable” is a restatement of “well designed”, in which case we can call it 10 questions.) There’s also a question tacked on there that I’m not sure I fully understand but seems most likely to be primarily opinion-based: "If so, why wouldn't the pharmaceutical produced a certified and expensive drug instead of a no-prescription drug?"

I think it’s reasonable to ask people to help you evaluate research on health topics. However, if you want a rigorous methodological answer, I would recommend narrowing it down to the study you think is most convincing, reading it yourself, and trying to formulate a more specific question.

As it stands, I think the duplicate closure is appropriate because it redirects to the original, more answerable question.

Comment: I think I see your point. So a question like "is topic A well researched in medical science", and giving some clinical studies as a start point, would be too broad?

Comment: @Fernando I think if you want an answer to specifically evaluate a particular study, it needs to be more focused. On the other hand, if you want to just ask the question, “Is there evidence that...?” then that should be fine. There are many questions like that here. They leave it up to answerers to decide which research they think is most pertinent to bring to bear. It’s great that you’ve done some initial research and found the studies; it’s just a little to much for somebody to analyze all of them. I imagine if you do a little more research you could figure out which is most important.

Comment: Also, @Fernando, I'm glad you brought this to meta. Just FYI, though, when you make a comment like [this](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/831/are-these-studies-about-red-algae-reducing-cold-virus-by-92-believable#comment1651_831), the person to whom you are directing the question is unlikely to see it unless you ping them by using `@` in front of the name. That's probably why you hadn't gotten an answer there.